# Backspace is not printing in this c program

Tags: c, escaping

I am trying to print escape sequences in this program:

```
/*print escape sequences*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int esc;
printf("Hit any escape sequence:");
esc=getchar();
//scanf("%d",&esc);
switch(esc){
    case '\t':
        printf("tab");
        break;
    case '\n':
        printf("newline");
        break;
    case '\b':
        printf("backspace");
        break;
    }
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

The thing is I tried doing this with `scanf` and it never printed anything.

Then I tried with `getchar` and it prints tab and newline. But backspace I couldn't get it to print backspaces.

How to print backspace?

Comment: How scanf("%d",&esc); is wrong?

Comment: Also the linked answer says that backspace = Ctrl+H. It says backspace is taken by interpreter than how it worked for newline?

Comment: `"%d"` format specifier is used to read `char` and not `int`.

Comment: Ok so I can send int values to get detected as escape sequence, and that works well with backspace too. If I make 'esc' as char it won't print backspace

Comment: I didn't say making `esc` a `char` is the solution. I said with `int`, it won't work even for other escape sequences.

Comment: I think that making esc as int is a solution. Making it char makes it hard to detect other escape sequences as 'enter' also comes into picture. Isn't it?

Comment: Always remember `"%d"` reads an integer that begins with a non-zero digit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110801/discussion-between-mrigendra-and-mohit-jain).